# How to update checkout page's layout according to specific condition?

Tags: magento2, checkout, layout

I wanto to add my custom block to checkout, if the conditions in cart are satisfied. Which steps should I follow?

Comment: Can you write more, placing your block etc?

Comment: I want to check cart conditions before the checkout page is rendered, then I want to add some custom block/template to checkout_index_index.xml to show on frontend if the conditions are satisfied in cart.